# how to do reshape in custom function in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to do reshape in custom function in tensorflow keras,

I'm trying to following kind of loss function in tensorflow as custom loss function,
#Since WRMSSE calucated for each stores so we have 3049 rows and 9180 time series

```
# Function to do quick rollups:
def rollup_nn(v):
    '''
    v - np.array of size (3049 rows, n day columns)
    v_rolledup - array of size (n, 9180)
    '''
    return roll_mat_csr*v #(v.T*roll_mat_csr.T).T


# Function to calculate WRMSSE:
key = 0
def wrmsse_nn(preds, y_true):
    '''
    preds - Predictions: pd.DataFrame of size (3049 rows, N day columns)
    y_true - True values: pd.DataFrame of size (3049 rows, N day columns)
    sequence_length - np.array of size (9180,)
    sales_weight - sales weights based on last 28 days: np.array (9180,)
    '''
    preds = preds[-(3049 * 28):]
    y_true = y_true.get_label()[-(3049 * 28):]
    preds = preds.reshape(28, 3049).T
    y_true = y_true.reshape(28, 3049).T    
    return 'wrmsse', np.sum(np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(rollup(preds-y_true)),axis=1)) * SW_store)/12,False
```

where I need to do the reshape in custom loss function
I 'm doing reshape function by using the following code

```
tf.reshape(preds,[28, 3049])
```

I'm getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

The complete error message is

```
Tensor("dense_23_target:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32) Tensor("dense_23_1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-05dfd1dadcca> in <module>()
      7 # model.add(Dense(units=16,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=initializer.he_normal(seed=0)))
      8 model.add(Dense(units=1))
----> 9 model.compile(loss=wrmsse_nn,optimizer='adam')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    440     self._setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    441     try:
--> 442       method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    443     finally:
    444       self._setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, distribute, **kwargs)
    447             else:
    448               weighted_loss = training_utils.weighted_masked_objective(loss_fn)
--> 449               output_loss = weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight, mask)
    450 
    451           if len(self.outputs) > 1:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
    661       # Update dimensions of weights to match with values if possible.
    662       score_array, _, weights = squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(
--> 663           score_array, None, weights)
    664       try:
    665         # Broadcast weights if possible.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/losses_utils.py in squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(y_pred, y_true, sample_weight)
     66     return y_pred, y_true, sample_weight
     67 
---> 68   y_pred_shape = y_pred.get_shape()
     69   y_pred_rank = y_pred_shape.ndims
     70   if (y_pred_rank is not None) and (weights_rank is not None):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Can u add complete traceback?

Comment: @AniketBote please find the complete error message thank you